# How to create google like instant search?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make an instant search from 2 weeks now,and there is no way guys,I tried all things that i know(which isn't much) I just fixed the errors,and from there. nothing.So I guess I don't need to explain you what code must do,because you all have search menus in your websites..One of big problems is (if it is problem) `$_ajax` ; `$_POST` methods,when I type the URL property to which info must be posted,it always is like browser URL not like a file if I put it like that `Food-Groups-BG.php` it will give error NOT FOUND ,no matter if the name is right or wrong. And at the moment my code isn't really do much and neither is giving any error. Just giving that in console http://prntscr.com/dtoonf.

Here is my code!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#food_search").keyup(function(event) {
        var search_term =$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/Food-Search",
            data:{fsearch:search_term},
            success:function(res) {
                $("#food_search_result").html(res);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="food-search" id="food_search"></p>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                               PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";
$databaseName = "dbName";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
if(isset($_POST['fsearch']) && $_POST['fsearch']!="") {
    $fsearch = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM food_data_bg WHERE search_term LIKE :title");
    $fsearch->execute(array(
        'title'=>'%'.$_POST['title'].'%'
    ));
    if($fsearch->rowCount()==0) {
        echo 'Не бяха намерени резултати!';
    } else {
        while($data=$fsearch->fetch()) {
        ?>
            <div class="search-result">
                <img src="<?php echo $data['fimage']; ?>" class="fimage"/>
                <span class="result-title"><?php echo $data['title'];?></span><br>
                <span class="calories-total"><?php echo $data['calories total'];?></span><br>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry,didn't really understand what are you saying by 2nd piece of code,in my Food-Search page is only php code which i used here in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [json_encode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on your php page in order to fetch the results properly! Echo your array like echo `json_encode($array);` also be aware that your page must not contain any headers therefore print it out on a empty page.

Comment: I am at university at the moment,will try after i go back to home,until then can you check if this is correct,i have some doubts that it isn't correct ;/
                                                                                                                   
http://pastebin.com/NjT4UgWm its a row from my code